# Create cardano transaction for wallet signing using Cardano Serialization Lib

Tags: transaction, cardano-serialization-lib

I am trying to generate a simple cardano transaction using Cardano Serialization Lib that simply sends some ADA. I want to sign the transaction using web3 wallet like Nami and verify that signature.

I have an issue with the verification part, however the first step is to ensure my transaction is absolutely correct. I would really appreciate if anyone with expertise could check if there are any obvious errors or mistakes with my functions below. FYI: input transaction hash is randomly chosen.

```
export function generateTxForSigning(sendAddressBech32: string, 
  receiveAddressBech32: string) {
  const txBuilderCfg = 
  csl.TransactionBuilderConfigBuilder.new().fee_algo(
      csl.LinearFee.new(
      csl.BigNum.from_str(“44”),
      csl.BigNum.from_str(“155381”)
    )
  )
    .coins_per_utxo_byte(csl.BigNum.from_str(“4310”))
    .pool_deposit(csl.BigNum.from_str(“500000000”))
    .key_deposit(csl.BigNum.from_str(“2000000”))
    .max_value_size(5000)
    .max_tx_size(16384)
    .prefer_pure_change(true)
    .build();

  const txBuilder = csl.TransactionBuilder.new(txBuilderCfg);

  // INPUT
  const sendAddress = csl.Address.from_bech32(sendAddressBech32);
  const baseAddress = csl.BaseAddress.from_address(sendAddress);
  if (!baseAddress) {
    return;
  }

  const pubKeyHash = baseAddress.payment_cred().to_keyhash();
  if (!pubKeyHash) {
    return;
  }

  const txInputHash = “ff8145628286711636d13c34bc07a8a8eb62b2f1aad954cf172c2abd5b1e6d30”
  const txInputIndex = 3;

  txBuilder.add_key_input(
    pubKeyHash,
      csl.TransactionInput.new(
      csl.TransactionHash.from_hex(txInputHash),
      txInputIndex
    ),
    csl.Value.new(csl.BigNum.from_str(“161826921”))
  );

  // OUTPUT
  const receiveAddress = csl.Address.from_bech32(receiveAddressBech32);
  txBuilder.add_output(
    csl.TransactionOutput.new(
      receiveAddress,
      csl.Value.new(csl.BigNum.from_str(“159826921”))
    )
  );

  // TIME TO LIVE
  const ttl = getCardanoSlot() + 5 * 60; //5 minutes
  txBuilder.set_ttl_bignum(csl.BigNum.from_str(ttl.toString()));

  // MIN FEE CALC
  txBuilder.add_change_if_needed(sendAddress);

  // CREATE TRANSACTION
  const transaction = csl.Transaction.new(
    txBuilder.build()
    csl.TransactionWitnessSet.new()
    undefined
  );

  // RETURN FOR WALLET SIGNING
  return transaction.to_hex();
}

export function getCardanoSlot() {
  const nowUnixTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const startShelleyUnixTimestamp = nowUnixTimestamp - 1596491091;
  return startShelleyUnixTimestamp + 4924800;
}
```